# Svn : I can't checkout from the same server

Tags: svn

I'm not pretty familiar with svn. I'm trying to install it and make it work for the first time on a Server. I have installed it behind Apache and it seems to work from another computer with Eclipse or TortoiseSVN but when I try to make a checkout from the same server i get no response (and then a timeout).

My repository is : /var/svn/forge

/var/svn/forge/conf/svnserve.conf :

```
  [general]
  ### ... ###
  anon-access = none
  auth-access = write
  ### ... ###
  password-db = passwd
  ### ... ###
  # authz-db = authz
  ### ... ###
  # groups-db = groups
  ### ... ###
  realm = forge
  ### ... ###
```

/var/svn/forge/conf/passwd :

```
[users]
antoine antoine
maria maria
jenkins jenkins
```

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn   
  SVNPath /var/svn/forge
</Location>
```

The command i use to do the chekout :

```
svn checkout svn://myip:apachePort/svn
```

thx for the help

Comment: have you tried using localhost 127.0.0.1 instead of myip?

Comment: Sorry if I was long to respond. Same result with 127.0.0.1 ...

Comment: Can you post the output of the checkout that doesn't work? Sounds like a svn client issue?